# Install xap file on windows phone

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, xap

I'm create simple aplication and get .xap file from visual studio 2015 (Apache cordova).

How install this app on windows phone before transfer on windows store.

Now when try install get error: Cannot install company app on windows phone 8.

Comment: At first glance this question looks off-topic because is about *general computing hardware and software* but it *directly involves tools used primarily for programming*

Answer (score 1):

You have to developer unlock the windows phone first... Then you can install upto 2 developer apps at once. 
You can unlock your phone with Windows Phone SDK

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769508%28v=vs.105%29.aspx